# Generate Checkstyle HTML report with Gradle

Tags: gradle, checkstyle, build.gradle

I'd like to get the output of running Checkstyle via Gradle as an HTML report.

I've found nothing in the [Checkstyle plugin documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.Checkstyle.html).

I've added the following to my `build.gradle` file.

```groovy
checkstyleTask {
    reports {
        html {
            destination "build/reports/checkstyle.html"
        }
    }
}
```

but this yielded

> What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'MyProject'.
>
> > Could not find method checkstyleTask() for arguments [build_1vu33nc0ekgtoo19jt e86o8o42$_run_closure8@1d8ee20] on root
> >     project 'MyProject'.

Is there a way to generate Checkstyle HTML reports using Gradle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's how I do it in a smal project of mine:

```
checkstyleMain << {
    ant.xslt(in: reports.xml.destination,
             style: new File('config/checkstyle-noframes-sorted.xsl'),
             out: new File(reports.xml.destination.parent, 'main.html'))
}
```

This requires that you store the checkstyle-noframes-sorted.xsl file, from the contrib directory of the checksyle binary distribution, in the `config` directory of your project.

If you can afford running a SonarQube server, using the sonar plugin leads to a much better user experience, though.

EDIT: The above won't work if there are violations. This should in all cases:

```
task checkstyleHtml << {
    ant.xslt(in: checkstyleMain.reports.xml.destination,
             style: file('/config/checkstyle-noframes-sorted.xsl'),
             out: new File(checkstyleMain.reports.xml.destination.parent, 'main.html'))
}

checkstyleMain.finalizedBy checkstyleHtml
```

Comment: Thanks, that HTML looks great. I found the XSL file [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/trunk/checkstyle/checkstyle-noframes-sorted.xsl).

Comment: I wanted to add that your statement about SonarQube is definitely true. I'm using an ensemble of Jenkins, Gradle, and SonarQube now where Gradle calls SonarQube. I posted parts of this configuration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815072/get-link-to-sonar-dashboard-in-jenkins-when-calling-gradle-sonarrunner) if someone is planning to have a similar build setup.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to work--at least with the latest Gradle--if the checkstyle checks fail. :-(

Comment: @jszakmeister Yeah I noticed that too just now. I modified it so that it should work even if there are violations. Check the edit. In case the edit is revoked for whatever reason, the trick is just to define OP's code as a separate task (e.g. 'checkstyleHtml'), and then add `checkstyleMain.finalizedBy checkstyleHtml`. You'll need to change OP's code from `reports.xml...` to `checkstyleMain.reports.xml...`.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like I'm late to the party. But still posting this thinking it might help someone else with the same issue.

Gradle 2.10 supports html file report generation. Just make sure you have version configured properly in your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file.

After that in your `build.gradle` file you should have a configuration like the below one.

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

checkstyle {
    toolVersion = '6.4.1'
    sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
    configFile = rootProject.file("config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml");
    showViolations = true
    ignoreFailures = true
}

checkstyleTest {
    enabled = false
}

tasks.withType(Checkstyle) {
  reports {
    html.destination rootProject.file("build/reports/checkstyle.html")
  }
}
```

Here the `config file` is the file which has the checkstyle modules that you want to use and `html.destination` is the location where you want your html report to be generated.

Answer (score 1):

For Gradle 2.10, add the following code to your `build.gradle`:

```
tasks.withType(Checkstyle) {
  reports {
    html.enabled = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/anshulverma/gradle-estilo-plugin) is a plugin that will make setting up checkstyle a breeze. It automatically sets up all the required configuration for checkstyle as per your liking and generates a HTML report in the end.

All you need to do is add a few lines to your `build.gradle` and thats it. No need to create separate xml files.

The plugin is called **estilo**. You can find more details on how to use it here -- https://github.com/anshulverma/gradle-estilo-plugin