# Get link to Sonar dashboard in Jenkins when calling 'gradle sonarRunner'

Tags: jenkins, gradle, sonarqube, sonar-runner

With the Jenkins build step `Invoke Standalone Sonar Analysis` (which is available via the [Sonar plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Jenkins+Plugin)) you get this nice link to the SonarQube dashboard in the job overview:
[image: sonar link].

I'm not using this build step due to [an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779791/fixing-class-is-not-accessible-through-the-classloader-warning-with-jenkins) but rather have a build step that calls `gradle sonarRunner`:
[image: gradle sonarRunner]

This is the part of my `build.gradle` configuring Sonar:

```
sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties {
    property "sonar.projectKey", projectId
    property "sonar.projectName", projectName

    // Address of SonarQube server
    property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000"

    // Database config
    property "sonar.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true"
    property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    property "sonar.jdbc.username", "root"
    property "sonar.jdbc.password", "superSecret"
    }
}
```

This works great: Just as with the `Invoke Standalone Sonar Analysis` build step, I can browse SonarQube's results at `http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/jutilsId`.

Unfortunately, this way the link to the SonarQube dashboard is gone from Jenkins' job overview.

[This blog entry](http://eugenedvorkin.com/code-quality-analysis-in-deployment-pipeline-with-gradle-jenkins-and-sonar/) describes how to achieve what I want but seems to be outdated as I can find no option in SonarQube's configuration that says `Check if this project is NOT built with maven 2`.

Is there any way I can have this link and use `gradle sonarRunner`?

---

My system:

I'm using SonarQube Server 4.1.1, [Gradle Plugin 1.23](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin), [Sonar Plugin 2.1](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sonar+plugin), Sonar Runner 2.3 and `gradle --version` gives:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.10
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2013-12-17 09:28:15 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     36ced393628875ff15575fa03d16c1349ffe8bb6

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.7.0_21 (Oracle Corporation 23.7-b01)
OS:           Linux 3.10-2-486 i386
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Sidebar-Link Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sidebar-Link+Plugin) to the rescue!

1. Install the plugin.
2. Put the [sonar icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hin2x.jpg) into `/var/lib/jenkins/userContent`. That's inside `JENKINS_HOME`. If you don't know where `JENKINS_HOME` is, take a look in the config file at `/etc/default/jenkins`.
3. Set up the link like this in the
   job's configuration (your URL will be different): [image: sidebar link config]
4. Done